# Function takes arbitrary number of matrices as arguments and returns all matrices in a list (R)

Tags: r, list, matrix, user-defined-functions, apply

I must define a function which takes an arbitrary number of matrices as arguments and returns all matrices in a list, where in all returned matrices the missing values have been removed.

I've already wrote the code for one variable

```
applyDropNaMatrix <- function(X){
apply_mat_list <- apply(Y, MARGIN=1, function(Z) Z[!is.na(Z[])])
return(apply_mat_list) 
}
```

I need to implement this function for a higher number of variables (namely the argument "..."). SOLUTION (I was not allowed to use "complete.cases(x)"

```
applyDropNaMatrix <- function(...) sapply( list( ... ) , function(X) X[rowSums(is.na(X))==0 , ], simplify=F)
```

THANK YOU VERY MUCH! YOU "SAVED" MY WEEK END :D

Comment: Your function to drop NA will most likely transform your matrices into lists, is that what you want it to do?

Comment: Well, actually the final result has to be a list of the matrices that I give as input. Your observation is quite smart, because if I delete NAs these matrices are not matrices anymore... Maybe I should delete the entire rows, which contains NA elements..

Comment: -1 `I was not allowed to use "complete.cases(x)`. This is the most ridiculous (ab)use of Stack Overflow; not only was it homework, but it was artificially constrained for the purpose of **you** learning something **on your own**. What's the point of getting other people to spend time on it?

Comment: Dear baptiste, thank you for your judgment. I spent a lot of time trying to solve this excercise and didn't want to cheat. I made the part of "complete.cases(x)" on my own. I only needed an hint and thanks to the others I've learnt much more than I could have done alone. I think that's the point having to do with a community. I'm honest and I admit that this hint helped me to solve the exercise. What's the problem with that? I really don't catch that.

Comment: Obviously I cannot answer for @baptiste, but I think there is no inherent problem in homework questions, if there is a minimum understanding of the problem and the OP has done some research on his own. Maybe next time it would be better if you clearly specified it was homework, to avoid people thinking you just want someone to do your homework for you (not the case here). Anyway, no harm done, glad you solved your problem. PS: there is [a post on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255477/please-clarify-the-policy-on-homework-questions) about homework.

Comment: ok, I may have over-reacted, but I hope you see the reason: there's a big difference between a genuine programming question, and one that was devised solely for an artificial assignment and with educational purpose. Always make it very clear if it's homework, so people can make an informed choice of response.

Comment: ok, I'm sorry.. I didn't think about that. Next time I will make that clear. I don't want to use this community to my personal purposes and that I really appreciate what you do. :)

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you need (works for any type really, not only matrices)

```
put.in.list <- function(...)
  {
  list(...)
  }
```

To remove the `NA` I would suggest:

```
my.list <- put.in.list(m1, m2, m3, m4)
my.list.no.NA <- sapply(my.list, function(x){m[complete.cases(m),]}, simplify=F)
```

Note that `simplify=F` forces the output to a list, otherwise the output may be simplified to a matrix, if all the members of the list are compatible.

Comment: Obviously, since it is just one line, there is no real need for a function... you could just write `list(m1, m2, m3, m4)`. However, you may want to process the NAs directly in the function.

Comment: You could boil it down to `put.in.list <- function(...) lapply( list( ... ) , function(x) x[ complete.cases(x) , ] )`

Comment: thank you very much! But I'm not allowed to use "complete.cases(x)", because our professor likes to make us going crazy! :P I'll try to find some alternatives..